# 2NF with a transitive dependency?

Tags: database, database-design, dependencies, normalization, database-normalization

Tomorrow I have my final exam of Database Design but I have a doubt about the Second Normal Form (2NF).

The definition says a relation is in 2NF if no non-prime attribute is partially dependent on a key.

My doubt is about if a relation could be in 2NF is if has attributes that are fully dependent on a key but transitively.

For example:
R (A,B,C,D) with AB key and FD ( AB->C,C->D)

In this case the non-prime attribute C is fully dependent on the key so it meets the condition but in the case of the attribute D I don´t know if it meets the rule.
 D is dependent on C and due to C is fully dependent on the key,does it mean that D is fully dependent on the key being this relation in 2NF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, D is transitively fully dependent on the key and this is valid in 2NF.  Transitive dependencies are addressed in 3NF.